# Instagram API, comment response without OAuth

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

I know there is two kinds of API provided by Instagram which with one of them you can read public comments and images and etc. (Graphql) and with another one you can authorize your app to do some stuff on Instagram on behalf of the authorized user.

In our company, we have an internal portal and **we want to add an ability to answer to company's comments directly from our portal**. Also customer service unit is in charge of this task and they can't have our company's Instagram credentials. **I want to know if there is a way to do such a task without any authentication from client side (for example, maybe I could add our Instagram credential from the portals back-end).**

Comment: I hope you have gone through the [Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/) page.
Yes, you can.